# Extjs: Check if element has a tooltip

Tags: javascript, extjs, tooltip

I am dynamically adding tooltips to elements depending on certain circumstances, but I dont want to change/add a tooltip if one already exists.

Is there a way to detect if a element/component already has a tooltip set?

Cheers

jj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no central registry to store tooltips. Depending on how you create your tooltips you could build your own hashtable to check for already created tooltips.